# Regex: Finding number by capturing but excluding

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex and I am really bad at it.
I've been trying to solve this problem but still can't get the result. So, I'm hoping that someone is able to assist me. thanks!

```
$str = "/tqrfq_58533_13";
preg_match_all('/\d+(?>=_)*/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches); // gets 58533, 13
```

but I only want '58533' and not both numbers. So I want the array of $matches to return '58533' as the only number

Comment: how about other cases?

Comment: If you want to find the number between the `_`, use `preg_match('~_(\d+)_~', $s, $matches)`, it will be in `$matches[1]`

Comment: There are a lot of solutions to get that number, what is the logic?

Comment: as in I don't want to have to call it from the array like that, I just want 1 definite value in the array, otherwise its messy lol, so it will always be $matches[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/(?<=_)(\d+)(?=_)/` as pattern in `preg_match()` that match digits between `_`

```
$str = "/tqrfq_58533_13";
preg_match('/(?<=_)(\d+)(?=_)/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; 
// 58533
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/tWsNK)

Also you can use `preg_replace()` if you don't want to get array as result

```
echo preg_replace('/.*?_(\d+)_.*/', "$1", $str);
// 58533
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/\d+(?=_)/', $str, $matches);
```

If you want to get only one number, remove `*` part since it means the result will be more than one. AFAIK, there is no such things like `(?>=_)`. I use `(?=_)` to indicate that `_` immediately follow the number.

You can see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more clarification.